# Operating temperature regulation

Tags: temperature, regulations

Is there a regulation that states which minimum ambient temperature range a commercial equipment must be operational? I.e., a mandatory range of temperature every industry must guarantee its products are operational?

Comment: Not every industry and not every application in every industry, no.

Comment: +1 on what Andy said but if you want commonly found temperature ranges, it's often -20 to +50 for consumer, -25 to +85 for industrial but your mileage may vary!

Comment: It varies a lot depending on the type of industry.  Are you talking about automotive, industrial, telecommunications, sensor technologies, etc?  And yes, any engineer is charge of a project must guarantee what they say it is operational at.

Comment: @12Lapointep Common consumer equipment, nothing automotive or industrial. Daily house appliances mostly.

Comment: @PDuarte Engineers will choose the appropriate electronics depending on the temperature requirements of the device.  Overall, it all depends on the manufacturer.